# Are the hoor women of this dunya who made it to paradise?

Tags: quran, women, jannah

In the Quran it is mentioned many times that in paradise there will be women who are pure and they will be the spouses of men. They are beautiful with large eyes and etc. As a woman, I’ve read the Quran and interpreted this as the description of the women who enter jannah from the dunya. However, now I feel let down reading that these are other women made in jannah for the sake of men. I heard some scholars believe that they are women from the dunya? Can you explain please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some difference in opinion though there's some textual evidence supporting the view that the Hoor Al Ayn are different from earthly women; a special maiden of Paradise. One [example](https://quran.com/55/56) is that the Qur'an says they are untouched by man or Jinn.. which isn't the case with earthly women because they've already been "touched" by their earthly husbands. Another [example](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2014) is the report that the Hoor Al-Ain actually speak out against earthly women when they annoy their husbands. Etc.

Don't feel let down, this won't subtract from you in any way. Earthly will still be more beautiful because of their worship (as per one interpretation) and still have as much time as they want with their husbands in Paradise (because they are the ones being rewarded, not the Hoor Al Ain). Jealousy also won't exist in Paradise, so you will be untroubled and ever-happy in Paradise inshaAllah.

Leave what is out of sight out of mind if it causes you jealousy of any kind; right now, your husband is just with you.. so enjoy this.